# Webpack the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using [drivelist](https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist) module with [bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings) dependency in my project. After I build it with webpack I receive the following warnings:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js 81:22-40 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js 81:43-53 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

And then in project if I do:

```
const bindings = require('bindings');
bindings('drivelist').list(callback);
```

I get an error, that we can't find `drivelist.node`.

> Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried: →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\build\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\build\Debug\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\build\Release\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\out\Debug\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\Debug\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\out\Release\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\Release\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\build\default\drivelist.node  →
>   Z:\Jscode\myapp\build\myapp\win64\compiled\8.1.4\win32\x64\drivelist.node

My webpack config is simple:

```
const config = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    target: 'node-webkit',
    node: {
        os: true,
        fs: true,
        child_process: true,
        __dirname: true,
        __filename: true,
        drivelist: true
    },
    plugins: []
};
```